# Is there a way to connect all query editors to the same connection in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS v18.10)

Tags: ssms

When I am composing a script in *SQL Server Management Studio **v18.10***, more often than not, I end up with plethora of recalcitrant **Query Editor** windows that each test one aspect of the problem (or my patience). Invariably I will need to test this ungovernable lot of scripts on different instances of SQL Server. I recently found out that there is a button to ***Disconnect All Queries***...

...Is there a button to ***Reconnect All Queries***?